# Should helm uninstall remove all docker images that were pulled on helm install?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

After I run `helm uninstall` I was expecting that it will remove all resources related to specific release, but images pulled on `helm install` are still there.

Is this expected behaviour and is there a easy way (flag perhaps) to remove images also?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kubernetes: How to automatically clean up unused images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58596782/kubernetes-how-to-automatically-clean-up-unused-images)

Comment: In Kubernetes you don't normally deal with "images" as a first-class concept.  There is a [garbage collector](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/kubelet-garbage-collection/) that will remove things for you.  If you're an administrator with login access directly to a node, you should expect to see it to take minutes (or longer) for an image to no longer be locally present once there aren't pods currently using it.

Comment: @DavidMaze I killed all pods 6 hours ago and I can still see images locally present, that is what confusing me.

Comment: In kubelet it's not time-based, it's space based. Won't clean until It needs space

Comment: docker-gc one removes an unused image immediately, so if you run that on a frequent cron schedule you might get close to what you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is expected. I believe image cache is handled on [CRI](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/container-runtimes/) level and helm / kubectl have no control over that, so there's no flag.

You can use projects like [docker-gc](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/spotify-docker-gc) to set up a cleaning schedule thru helm (running a GC daemonset), or rely on [kubelet's built-in GC](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/kubelet-garbage-collection/) controlled via kubelet process flags.